# convert base class unique_ptr to derived class unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

I need to convert my base class `unique_ptr` to a derived class `unique_ptr` so that I can access some of the functions of the derived class.

The code I have throws error.
What is going on wrong here?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Base
{};

class Derived : public Base
{
  public:
  Derived(int x):_x(x){}
  
  int oneDerivedClassFunction()
  {    return _x;  }
  
  private: 
    int _x;
};

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Base> basePtr;
    basePtr.reset(new Derived(10));
    
    auto der = std::unique_ptr<Derived>(dynamic_cast<Derived*>(basePtr.release())); // error here!
    printf("%d", der->oneDerivedClassFunction());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: PS: if your cast fails, you have a memory leak

Comment: BTW, you don't necessary need to transfer ownership for casting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `dynamic_cast` can't be used on non-[polymorphic types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object#Polymorphic_objects).

Depending on your intent, you could make `Base` polymorphic, e.g.

```
class Base
{
  public:
  virtual ~Base() {}
};
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/fhh7X4MkzAhxAFXp)

Or you can use `static_cast` instead, if you're sure about the conversion result.

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/MecKddvKaXWR8Nsj)

Comment: Note your example leaks the pointer if the `dynamic_cast` fails

Comment: @AlanBirtles I know, it depends on OP's intent. Either check the conversion result of `dynamic_cast`, or use `static_cast` instead. For the code showed by OP, the conversion result is determined.

Comment: In addition, virtual destructor solves also the UB when `Derived` is destroyed through `Base`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure about the conversion result, you can transfer the ownership without releasing.

```
std::unique_ptr<Derived> derivedPtr = std::move(*reinterpret_cast<std::unique_ptr<Derived>*>(&basePtr));
```

[DEMO](https://cpp.sh/?source=%23include%20%3Ciostream%3E%0D%0A%23include%20%3Cmemory%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Base%0D%0A%7B%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Derived%20%3A%20public%20Base%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20public%3A%0D%0A%20%20Derived(int%20x)%3A_x(x)%7B%7D%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20int%20oneDerivedClassFunction()%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20%20%20%20return%20_x%3B%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20private%3A%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20int%20_x%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aint%20main()%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20std%3A%3Aunique_ptr%3CBase%3E%20basePtr%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20basePtr.reset(new%20Derived(10))%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20std%3A%3Aunique_ptr%3CDerived%3E%20derivedPtr%20%3D%20std%3A%3Amove(*reinterpret_cast%3Cstd%3A%3Aunique_ptr%3CDerived%3E*%3E(%26basePtr))%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20printf(%22%25d%22%2C%20derivedPtr-%3EoneDerivedClassFunction())%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%200%3B%0D%0A%7D)